# Are there any mailto: characters I could use to have Outlook recognize specific body text as bold?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook, mailto

I am automating an email generation from a WebApp (react frontend) and I am using `mailto:` for this purpose. However, I can't find a way to make some specific text show in bold when filled in the email. Is there a special character or enclosure that will make Outlook recognize certain text segments as bold? My browser target is Chrome and Outlook 365 version 2306.

e.g.,

```
const body = encodeURIComponent('Some text that need a word or two >>>in bold<<<');
window.open(`mailto:some@email.domain?subject=...&body=${body}`);
```

Any other idea how to make this work?

I was also experimenting copy-pasting bold text from an Outlook email into an editor capable of displaying special characters e.g. Notepad++ but it just pastes the text content without any special characters which I presume Outlook would use to understand bold text.

Comment: Citing from the [RFC 6068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068) *"The "body" field value is intended to contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the   message."* So probably not ...